# How can I return success or failure to the operating system in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, errno

The simplest Unix tools are `true` and `false`, little programs that do nothing but return 0 and 1 respectively to the operating system and exit. An example in C might look like the below:

```
// true - does nothing successfully
int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

Through searching, I haven't been able to find a way to implement this kind of functionality in Haskell. Is there anything in the IO monad that can do this?

Comment: Don't forget `FileNotFound`. http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use one of the functions defined in [System.Exit](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Exit.html).

Answer (score 8):

See [System.Exit](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Exit.html).

Answer (score 7):

There are a [few `exit` functions](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Exit.html) you should be able to use.